# ActiveX component can't create object VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am getting an error while converting PPT to PDF as" ActiveX component can't create object VBA"

```
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim newslide As PowerPoint.SlideRange
    Dim slideCtr As Integer
    Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape
    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open"C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\ProcessCoach certificate template.pptx"
    Range("F8").Activate  'This cell had a date formatted as a date
    slideCtr = 1

    Set tb = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideCtr).Shapes("Text Box 4")
    tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "m/d/yyyy")

    'Error is here
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & _
 "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & _
 ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
```